# How to save only starting value in onSensorChanged() method?

Tags: android, rotation, sensors

I am using getRotationMatrix() to calculate v[0], v[1], v[2] and corresponding azimuth, pitch and roll values in onSensorChanged() method. I am wondering how to save only the first v[0] (or corresponding azimuth) value into firstAzimuth when boolean detectAzimuth becomes true?

```
private boolean detectAzimuth = false;
private float firstAzimuth;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    accValues = event.values.clone();
}

if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
    geoValues = event.values.clone();
}

boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(r, i, accValues,
    geoValues);

if (success) {
    SensorManager.getOrientation(r, v);

    if (detectAzimuth) {
    azimuth = v[0] * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
    pitch = v[1] * (180 / Math.PI);
    roll = v[2] * (180 / Math.PI);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if got the value of azimuth for first time. If you did not, get the value and make detectAzimuth as true. Then save the value in SharedPreference.

Now next time, check if you already took the value of azimuth the first time using the boolean variable `detectAzimuth`. If its true that means you already took it. hen get it from Sharedpreference and assign it to `firstAzimuth`. That eay you will always have the value of first value of `azimuth` taken.

```
if (success) {
    SensorManager.getOrientation(r, v);
    if (!detectAzimuth) {  // if not taken yet
        azimuth = v[0] * (180 / Math.PI); // take the value
        detectAzimuth = true; //make the bolean true to know that you've taken the value
        //Store in SharedPreference
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putFloat("firstAzimuth", azimuth);
        editor.commit();
    }else{ //if already taken value first time
        //get the first value from SharedPreference and assign it to firstAzimuth
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
        firstAzimuth = prefs.getFloat("firstAzimuth", 0.0);
        //take the new value
        azimuth = v[0] * (180 / Math.PI); // take the new value but don't store it
    }
    pitch = v[1] * (180 / Math.PI);
    roll = v[2] * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Just for your information, this will prevent you from taking further `azimuth` values as you already received one value and are checking everytime for its presence. I'm not sure if you want that or not. If not then we can discuss further about the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I would really appreciate if you could throw me some possibilities for taking (not saving) further azimuth values, while still saving only the first one, since as you were not sure, this is what I was aiming for.

Comment: Glad it helped. okay. See the updated code if you want to get the value but not save it(other than first time).

Comment: Excellent! Working like a charm. You rule.